# Assign each value of a list to another list of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists :

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

I want to assign list2 values to list1 variables. Simply put forward I want end result like this :

```
final_list = ['a' = 10, 'b' = 20, 'c' = 30, 'd' = 40, 'e' = 50]
```

What is the way to do in python3?

Comment: Use a dictionary, there's no such thing as your `final_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
res = dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

Output :

```
{'a': 10, 'c': 30, 'b': 20, 'e': 50, 'd': 40}
```